# Fail to connect to server when creating an EJBClient

Tags: java, ejb

I have an EJB Client as follow:

```
public class EJBTestClient {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {

    Properties jndiProps = new Properties();  
    jndiProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");  
    jndiProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"http-remoting://localhost:8080");  // create a context passing these properties  Context ctx = new InitialContext(jndiProps);
    jndiProps.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming"); 
    InitialContext context = new InitialContext(jndiProps);
    System.out.println("Context lookup finished");

    MyFirstEJBRemote proxy = (MyFirstEJBRemote) context.lookup("MyFirstEJB/Remote");
    System.out.println(proxy.getClass().toString());

    System.out.println(proxy.getDescription());

    proxy.doSomething();

  }
}
```

but when I run the program it showed an Exception `javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to any server. Servers tried: [http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080 (java.io.IOException: JBREM000202: Abrupt close on Remoting connection 0c05035f to /127.0.0.1:8080 of endpoint "config-based-naming-client-endpoint" <2ce1483d>)]`

And my EJB Container named EJBTestApp which contains *MyFirstEJB Stateless Session Bean* and *MyFirstEJBRemote Interface*:

```
@Stateless
@Remote
public class MyFirstEJB implements MyFirstEJBRemote {

private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyFirstEJB.class);
/**
 * Default constructor. 
 */
public MyFirstEJB() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void doSomething() {
    log.info("doSomething() has been call"); 

}

@Override
public String getDescription() {
    return "getDescription() has returned some values";
}

}
```

And this EJB Container is deployed on Wildfly 10  under localhost:8080. Can anyone help me how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to set

```
jndiProps.put(jboss.naming.client.ejb.context, true);
```

Add the libraries from wildfly10directory/bin/client to the project

If doesn't working, try to set lookup to:

```
MyFirstEJBRemote proxy = (MyFirstEJBRemote) context.lookup("MyFirstEJB/BeanName!path_to_package_remote_bean");
```

Comment: Hi, I dont really get your last setup. Let me summarize abit about my Project structure: My EJB Project named: EJBTestApp, inside it contains MyFirstEJB remote session bean and MyFirstEJBRemote Interface. So how the parameters inside the  my lookup() method should look like?

Comment: and full path to the MyFirstEJBRemote?
for example pl.razikus.ejb.MyFirstEJBRemote

    MyFirstEJBRemote proxy = (MyFirstEJBRemote) context.lookup("EJBTestApp/MyFirstEJB!pl.razikus.ejb.MyFirstEJBRemote");

And to what file you are packing your project? EJBTestApp.jar ?

Comment: no i did not pack my Project, instead i set the build path in my Client Project to the EJBTestApp

Comment: so, how do you deploy it? 
are you using any IDE?

Comment: i did tried like this: MyFirstEJBRemote proxy = (MyFirstEJBRemote) context.lookup("EJBTestApp/MyFirstEJB!src.MyFirst‌​EJBRemote");  but it still not working. Here is how my EJB Project looks like: [Link](https://s18.postimg.org/ein5nfzuh/image.png)

Comment: in my opinion you have to deploy application to your WildFly10 server

Comment: yes I did deploy the EJB Project to the WildFly Server and they are running also

Comment: check http://127.0.0.1:9990 after Wildfly start,
default admin admin,
Cart deployments, propably runtime,
Is there your JAR file? or ear or any deploy?

Comment: yes, inside the deployment tab, it contains already the EJBTestApp.jar file

Comment: try to remove that line too: jndiProps.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");

Comment: I still got that error :( 

Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to any server. Servers tried: [http-remoting://localhost:8080 (java.io.IOException: JBREM000202: Abrupt close on Remoting connection 7bfd161c to localhost/127.0.0.1:8080 of endpoint "config-based-naming-client-endpoint" <75eb0986>)]

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9fwrpnenqpj4xj1/KEY.zip?dl=0

This is source code of my project. I started it yesterday or 2 days ago so it's fresh. Bean's works, persistence too, server are the same. One is the client, one is the server